# Offline storage HTML5 using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple web mobile app that is calculating values in given fields. I've been trying to  save the values on the local host in the browser and haven't had any luck. I am using jQuery to save the values, but somehow it doesn't work.

```
     <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('#field_wc').val(localStorage.getItem('wc') );
$('#field_tax').val(localStorage.getItem('tax') );
$('#field_sui').val( localStorage.getItem('sui') );
$('#field_o').val( localStorage.getItem('o') );
$('#field_fp').val( localStorage.getItem('fp') );
$('#field_misc').val( localStorage.getItem('misc') );
$('#field_t').val( localStorage.getItem('t') );


    });

    $('#field_tax').keyup(function() {
$('#field_wc').val( localStorage.setItem('wc') );
$('#field_tax').val( localStorage.setItem('tax') );
$('#field_sui').val( localStorage.setItem('sui') );
$('#field_o').val( localStorage.setItem('o') );
$('#field_fp').val( localStorage.setItem('fp') );
$('#field_misc').val( localStorage.setItem('misc') );
$('#field_t').val( localStorage.setItem('t') );


    });
    </script>
```

Comment: your [`setItem`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#dom-storage-setitem) syntax is off `localStorage.setItem(key, value)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var
    key,
    fields = ['wc', 'tax', 'sui', 'o', 'fp', 'misc', 't'];

  for(key in fields) { 
    (function (){
      var
        name = fields[key],
        field = $('#field_' + name)
          .val(localStorage.getItem(name) || '')
          .on('keyup', function() {
            localStorage.setItem(name, field.val());
          });
    }());
  }
});
```

Hi! I optimized your script and fixed a few other problems with it: http://jsfiddle.net/q78d8/4/

- Using locally scoped variables to store the jQuery objects in is the biggest performance improvement. In your original script you made jQuery create those over and over again, for every keyup event fired
- I think you wanted to bind each input to the "Save" function, but realize, you don't have to update values which haven't changed! If the user updated #field_tax, only save that value
- Remember you can Chain jQuery methods
- I used a little trick here, where I know that the return value of each chain, would still be the jQuery object I originally selected, so I could store the object in the same line in which I assigned a keyup handler on it & filled the value with what was in the localstorage
- I wrapped the whole thing in a for loop, and an self-invoking function, to create an easy-to-do-maintenance-on script

**Edit --**
I left out that you used setItem incorrectly, since others already told you.

Comment: I did encountered another problem where all the values seem to be in local storage when I refresh the browser, but when a inspect them in the console and check the value they come as undefined. Once I change one of the files and run a calculation they seem to get defined.

Comment: Fixed it for you, I added || '', which changes undefined into an empty string.

Comment: I tried and it still doesn't work. I might have issues with the rest of my java script. here is the link to the site http://myswitcharoo.com/m/appv2.1.html . The idea is to do auto calculations on the main page and keep the settings in localstorage.

Answer (score 1):

As mdmullinax said, your setItem syntax is the problem.  Also, you may want to abstract those calls, as well as checking that the key yet exists.  Here's the basic abstraction layer I use; I also namespace my keys to avoid clashes between different scripts.  The isJSON argument is optional, depending if I want to get back a stored JSON string, or have a stored JSON string converted back to an object for me.
Also, your keyup should be inside of document ready, and (assuming you're using the latest jQuery [1.7.1]), you'd probably want to use .on() instead of .keyup()

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var namespace = 'user1078259';

    storage = {
        check: function (key) {
            key = storage.nsKey(key);
            return localStorage.hasOwnProperty(key);
        },

        nsKey: function (key) {
            return namespace + '_' + key;
        },

        read: function (key, isJSON) {
            key = storage.nsKey(key);
            return isJSON || 0 ? JSON.parse(storage.read(key)) : localStorage.getItem(key);
        },

        store: function (key, valueToStore, isJSON) {
            key = storage.nsKey(key);
            localStorage.setItem(key, isJSON || 0 ? JSON.stringify(valueToStore) : valueToStore);
        }
    };

    $('#field_wc').val(storage.check ? storage.read('wc') : '')
    $('#field_tax').val(storage.check ? storage.read('tax') : '')
    $('#field_sui').val(storage.check ? storage.read('sui') : '')
    // and so on...

    $('#field_tax').on('keyup', function() {
        storage.store('wc', $('#field_wc').val());
        storage.store('tax', $('#field_wc').val());
        storage.store('sui', $('#field_wc').val());
        // and so on...
    });
```

});

Answer (score 1):

It appears your issue is that you're using the `localStorage.setItem` API incorrectly. You need both a key and a value to store.

Here's a localStorage primer:

```
// set
localStorage.setItem('blah', 'blahblah')

// check if it is set
localStorage.getItem('blah')

// check how many items are stored
localStorage.length

// another way to get the item 
localStorage.key(0);

// remove the item
localStorage.removeItem('blah')
```

[Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taylorbuley/xdxYA/) with a tiny library I wrote for show and tell purposes. It allows objects or strings to be added to localstore via `JSON.parse` and `stringify`.

Hit 'run' a few times and the output should look like:

```
blah is not set. setting to blahblah
["blah"]
blah is set to blahblah
[]
blah is not set. setting to blahblah
["blah"]
blah is set to blahblah
[]
```